# .jar file works in IntelliJ but JVM error occurs when .jar is run outside of IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, jvm

I am new to Java and Stack Overflow, and I have created a Java project in IntelliJ, and made a .jar file to run it without IntelliJ by building artifacts, and building the .jar file. The program uses a robot to open a Run window by pressing the Windows and R keys, moves the mouse to the inside of the box for my computer's resolution (1366 x 768), clicks, types cmd and presses enter, moves the mouse inside of the cmd window, clicks, and types whoami and presses enter. This works completely fine inside of IntelliJ, but outside of it I get this error:

Java Virtual Machine Launcher
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.

When I click OK, this other text box opens up:

Java Virtual Machine Launcher
A java Exception has occurred.

My code in my .java file is:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class RobotTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        while (true) {
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
            r.mouseMove(300,620);
            r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            Thread.sleep(100);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            Thread.sleep(150);
            r.mouseMove(400,200);
            r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            r.mouseMove(400, 200);
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        }
    }
}
```

The Thread.sleep(20000); at the end of the code is there to prevent it from being in an infinite loop, allowing me to stop the program.

My java is up to date, so is IntelliJ, and I do not see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So when you build the project, does intellij create a jar in the `target` folder ?
This is what you should run from the command line.
I suspect, if it is creating it then the libraries are not being included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming full error looks something like this:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: robot/RobotTest has been
>   compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file
>   version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class
>   file versions up to 52.0

I'd say you may have conflicting JDK/JRE installations in your system. As the error states, the .jar was compiled by a more recent version of the Java runtime (the one IntelliJ IDEA uses), whereas the one you are using now is of an older version.

- Check which version of JDK is used to run your project in IntelliJ IDEA (**File | Project Structure | Project SDK**). JDK 12 in my case.
- Run the following in command prompt:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

- If they are different, uninstall the older environment and rerun the JAR.

In my case java was version 1.8, whereas javac was version 12. I uninstalled the 1.8 JRE from my system, made sure `java -version` gave me 12 as well and and reran `java -jar path\to\artifact.jar` from cmd successfully.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! My problem was fixed, because I had a version of Java that was released 2 years ago, and I had JDK 13 installed on my computer! Thanks! :)